# Вываливается заголовок, flexbox, позиционирование

Tags: html, css, flexbox, позиционирование

Когда добавляю в блок заголовок,блок флекс-бокса просто сыпится, надо,чтобы в блоке был заголовок и текстовый абзац, и при в родительском блоке еще один блок с картинкой,и разбить их space-around(ом)
Надеюсь не много воды и суть вопроса ясна
Благодарю
Вот скрин.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYxsa.jpg

```css
.section .flexitem-1
{
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: left;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  height: 400px;
}

.section p
{
  font-size: 1.4em;
}

.section .flexitem-2
{
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-flow: row-reverse wrap;
  align-items: center;
  height: 400px;
}

.section .adaptive-img
{
  width: 600px;
}

.section .flexitem-3
{
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  height: 400px;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<!-- <div class="about-me">
  <h1>Приветствую</h1><br>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque excepturi, magnam dolorum itaque, fugiat quae.</p>
</div> -->
<div class="section">
  <div class="cross flexitem-1">
    <img class="cross-img" src="img/cross.png" alt=""><!-- <div > -->
      <!-- <h2>Кроссбраузерность</h2> --><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat voluptatibus cumque necessitatibus aperiam quas, laudantium perferendis vel, voluptates nulla distinctio, corrupti quibusdam libero omnis error quae ea sequi consequuntur nam.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="section">
      <div class="adaptive flexitem-2">
        <!-- <h2>Адаптивность</h2><br> -->
        <img class="adaptive-img" src="img/adaptive.png" alt=""><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus temporibus, nulla! Ex ratione expedita voluptas eos saepe. Iusto sit, vitae.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  <div class="section">
    <div class="creativity flexitem-3">
      <!-- <h2>Креативность</h2><br> -->
     <img class="creativity-img" src="img/crativ.jpg" alt=""><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi atque porro maxime numquam harum nam, veniam sunt architecto magni, cum quasi ratione molestias molestiae doloribus neque adipisci commodi totam, dicta.</p><br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- <div class="section">
    <div class="fast-and-light flexitem-4">
      <h2>Быстрый и легкий</h2><br>
      <span class="fast-img"></span><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi atque porro maxime numquam harum nam, veniam sunt architecto magni, cum quasi ratione molestias molestiae doloribus neque adipisci commodi totam, dicta.</p><br>
    </div>
  </div> -->
</div>
```

[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]

```
  [1]:
```

Comment: можно весь код с картинками..

Comment: Где вы хотите чтобы заголовок был? Над текстом?
Если да, засуньте текст в один общий блок.

Comment: @Алексей,дак в том и дело,что оно в общем блоке
Я хочу сделать один блок, в нем картинка и блок и их разбить на две части space-around

<div class="section">
        <div class="cross flexitem-1">
          <img class="cross-img" src="img/cross.png" alt=""><!-- <div > -->
            <!-- <h2>Кроссбраузерность</h2> --><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat voluptatibus cumque necessitatibus aperiam quas, laudantium perferendis vel, voluptates nulla distinctio, corrupti quibusdam libero omnis error quae ea sequi consequuntur nam.</p>
          </div>

Comment: Скажите, что вы хотите увидеть в конечном итоге?
Блок с картинкой + блок с текстом ( сверху заголовок, снизу текст) все это одной строчкой, так?

Comment: @Алексей да,совершенно верно. раскидать их по краям родительского блока

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Советую сделать общий универсальный класс, чтобы не задавать одинаковые свойства классам. В данном примере универсальный класс - section__item. Скорее всего у вас была проблема, что вы не закрыли div

```css
.section p
{
    font-size: 1.4em;
}




.section__item{
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: -o-flex;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    height: 400px;
 
}
.section__item img{
    background-color:#000;
    width: 600px;
    height:300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <!-- <div class="about-me">
      <h1>Приветствую</h1><br>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque excepturi, magnam dolorum itaque, fugiat quae.</p>
    </div> -->
    <div class="section">
        <div class="section__item cross flexitem-1">
            <img class="cross-img" src="img/cross.png" alt="">
            <div>
                <h2>Кроссбраузерность</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat
                    voluptatibus cumque necessitatibus aperiam quas, laudantium perferendis vel, voluptates nulla
                    distinctio,
                    corrupti quibusdam libero omnis error quae ea sequi consequuntur nam.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
        <div class="section__item adaptive flexitem-2">
            <div>
                <h2>Кроссбраузерность</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat
                    voluptatibus cumque necessitatibus aperiam quas, laudantium perferendis vel, voluptates nulla
                    distinctio,
                    corrupti quibusdam libero omnis error quae ea sequi consequuntur nam.</p>
            </div>
            <img class="adaptive-img" src="img/adaptive.png" alt="">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
        <div class="section__item creativity flexitem-3">
            <img class="creativity-img" src="img/crativ.jpg" alt="">
            <div>
                <h2>Кроссбраузерность</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat
                    voluptatibus cumque necessitatibus aperiam quas, laudantium perferendis vel, voluptates nulla
                    distinctio,
                    corrupti quibusdam libero omnis error quae ea sequi consequuntur nam.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- <div class="section">
      <div class="fast-and-light flexitem-4">
        <h2>Быстрый и легкий</h2><br>
        <span class="fast-img"></span><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi atque porro maxime numquam harum nam, veniam sunt architecto magni, cum quasi ratione molestias molestiae doloribus neque adipisci commodi totam, dicta.</p><br>
      </div>
    </div> -->
</div>
```